# Regex match equation strings

Tags: regex, pcre

Hi I'm trying to make a regex for matching simple math equations strings such as:

```
565+9^4/22*5
```

I want to only allow to following arthemithic operators: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^`, `%`

and the equation has no set length, it can be as long as it the user wants it to be.

I tried using something like:

`\d+[+\-*\/^%]\d+`

That matches for example:

`2*3+3+3`

But it doesn't match:

`2*3+3`

Comment: If my answer is correct, please mark it as such to close this topic

Answer (score 4):

You need to repeat matches for a "number and operator" combination. So you are looking for:

```
(\d+[+\-*\/^%])*(\d+)
```